# Cannot read property 'FACEBOOK' of null, js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, expo, base64, share, file-sharing

I would like to use react-native-share in a react native project with EXPO. I get this error when starting the application!

```
const myCustomShare = () => {
    const options = {
      message: "some words"
    }
    Share.open(options)
    .then(res =>console.log(res))
    .catch(err =>console.log(err));
  };
```